# AJAX Sending empty strings but in console I see them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have some problem, seems like I can't solve it...

I have code

```
$(document).on("click","#location-routes .fa-floppy-disk",function(){
    let route = [];
    let job = $(this).closest('.row').attr('job');
    $(this).closest('.row').find('input').each(function () {
        route[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    route['location'] = alias;
    $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          url: "white.php",
          data: {job: job, info:  JSON.stringify(route)},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
              }
        });
        
    console.log(route);
});
```

In console, I see what should be, but ajax is sending empty query.

I also use jquery ui autocomplete, and google map api at this page.
Please, help me to fix it.

Comment: You've defined `route` as an array but are treating it like an object. When you stringify it, it will be an empty array. Use `const route = {}` instead

Comment: Thank you! 
This is perfect platform with perfect people!

Comment: @freedomn-m don't trust the JSFiddle in-page console to act identically to the actual browser console

Comment: @Phil thanks, I normally don't use it but it was open already.  Real console works as OP expects.

Comment: Can you check the white.php file maybe you have printed something else there in another call?

Comment: I fixed it with @Phil 's answer. Thank you all!